# Is the Google Home exactly the same as the Google Assistant?

Tags: google-assistant

So I'm considering getting a Google Home. I have a Nexus 6p which has the google assistant. I'm just wondering, is the Google Home basically just a device with only the Google Assistant installed?

Does Google Home offer any features or benefit over just a phone with Google Assistant?

Answer (score 3):

> Does Google Home offer any features or benefit over just a phone with Google Assistant?

Sure does.

1. Hands-free.
2. Multiple users.
3. Control your smart home.
4. Control music
   (and it has a hi-fi speaker built-in)
5. Just to name a few things.

https://madeby.google.com/home/